# Phpmyadmin in cpanel importing a database doesnt work

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

Ok, so i log into cpanel. In mysql databases there is one db called db_movies. One user is added to that db. 
Then i go into phpmyadmin, click on db_movies and try to import a db I made in my local phpmyadmin. 
I got this error:

```
Error SQL query:
--
-- Database: `db_movies`
-- CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  `db_movies` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1044 - Access denied for user 'xxx@localhost' to database 'db_movies'
```

I'm not sure what seems to be the problem. Access denied? But i can do everything manually in that phpmyadmin; i can create a table, insert rows etc. why cant I import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to grant ALL :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `b_movies` . * TO  'youruser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION ;
```

Or maybe you are missing the "CREATE' privilege :

```
GRANT CREATE ON  `b_movies` . * TO  'youruser'@'%';
```

Edit: so try this

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'youruser'@'%';
```

Comment: this user (one and only) already has ALL PRIVILEGES checked (in cpanel). i triple checked that and now i tried to create new db with new user with all privileges. but its the same thing... And if i run that sql command in phpmyadmin it throws error:  #1045 - Access denied for user '***'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Ok i managed to import. I edited exported sql file and removed following lines

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_movies DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; USE db_movies;

and then imported.. :)

Comment: yep! so you are missing privileges to create a DB. glad it is working now